# MS Access Query matching month from two date fields

Tags: ms-access-2010

I'm new to Access and am trying to figure out the best way to write a query.  I have a table that tracks security entry information for each employee which has an Employee ID field and a date field [ENTRYDATE].  Another table (tblSPACE) lists out where that employee sits and is updated each month with new information. There is a field in tblSPACE which tracks what month the information is from. [ASOFMONTHYEAR].  These two tables are related by a unique employee ID number.  What I want to do is have a query that shows the entry information and the corresponding seat that that employee was in for that month.  I'm thinking I need to add a criteria into one of the date fields to have it match the month of the other date field? Something like Where Month(tblSpace.ASOFMONTHYEAR) = Month(tblEntry.ENTRYDATE).  But of course that doesn't work.  Any guidance on how I should go about this?  Sorry if I've not explained this well.

Comment: Step back, take a breath, and then [edit] your question. Start by explaining the problem you're trying to solve; you can add paragraph breaks to the text to make it readable. Then post your table information, along with column names and sample data, the results you'd like to get from that data, and the query you've tried that isn't working as you'd like. Then you can ask a specific question, and we can try to help. :-)

Comment: What he said. Your question is hardly understandable. You should restructure that and post a sample of your data if you want an answer.